# React native image from Parse

Tags: image, parse-platform, addition, react-native

I am trying to add the image from Parse to React Native Project.
Everything is ok with adding text:

```
<Text style={{flex: 1, fontSize: 14, textAlign: 'justify', color: 'black', }}>
     {this.props.tweet.get('username')}
</Text>
```

But I can not add an image:

```
<Image  source={this.props.tweet.get('photo')}
style={{width: 50, height: 50}}/>
```

I am also trying

```
var photo = this.props.tweet.get('photoprofile');
....code
  <Image  source={{uri: {photo}}}
   style={{width: 50, height: 50}}/>
```

And

```
var photo = this.props.tweet.get('photoprofile');
....code
<Image  source={photo}
   style={{width: 50, height: 50}}/>
```

It does not work.

Comment: You should have mentioned the prototype of object you are working on. And adding uri in source with correct image url will work.

Answer (score 0):

Everything work!!!

```
var imageFile = this.props.tweet.get('photoprofile');
var imageURL = imageFile.url();  
...code
<Image  source=  {{uri: imageURL}}
              style={{width: 50, height: 50}} />
```